# Can REDCap action tags call upon a variable in different forms?

Tags: redcap

I am trying to use the @CALCDATE action tag to calculate a target date. The start date is in the same arm but in a different form from where I am trying to use the action tag.

I have it formatted exactly as the example from REDCap, but do not get a calculated date output.
@CALCDATE([baseline_date], 6, 'd')

Including the arm and event of the baseline date makes no difference either.
@CALCDATE([baseline_event_2][baseline_date], 6, 'd')

My source field and result fields are both formatted in as text fields with date validation. I have also tried with datetime _second validation as well.

In this example, the action tag should provide a target date 6 days after the baseline_date.

Could the fact the variables are in different forms be causing the action tag not to work? Can anyone suggest some solutions or ideas as to why it might not be working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should allow it. Try piping it into a label to see if it goes in there, just to make sure there isn't something else wrong.